# Rails: Ajax auto-suggest plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, plugins, autocomplete

Is there a rails (or other javascript framework) plugin  that does the auto suggest like the Related Questions suggestions here in Stack Overflow where after leaving the text field a list of related items shows up?

Also is there a name for this UI patterm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an [auto_complete](http://github.com/rails/auto_complete/tree/master) plugin for Rails, which I believe can be used to achieve that effect. Just prevent it from filling the text input, and use a bigger div with links.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you can use this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jq-autocomplete

I've used it before and it's easy enough to configure.